# Save positions of vector in another vector

Tags: c++, vector, indexing, iterator

I have a vector of points and generate some geometrics with those points. To save memory, I use the index of the vector as reference and not the point itself.

Example:

```
Triangle(index[0], index[4], index[6]);
```

instead of

```
Triangle(Point(x0, y0), Point(x4, y4), Point(x6, y6));
```

However, I need to store some positions for later reference. 
Is it preferable to save it as int or as iterator? How much space does that iterator take compared to the int?

Specific: 
Do I do
`std::vector<int> laterUse;`
or
`std::vector< std::vector<Point>::const_iterator >` ?

What are the advantages or disadvantages? I'm more interested in saving memory than in speed.

Comment: iterators will become invalid as soon as you modify the collection they iterate on. Indices are better, but you need to make guarantees that no reordering of the collection happens. I would instead store `Point*`

Comment: `Point*` may also become invalid if the actual object is stored in a vector that is modified. If the vector is not going to be modified, I think integer and pointers will yield the same solution in terms of memory, but pointers save one indirection.

Comment: Pointers are an interesting idea. However I never quite worked them out for me. Instead of going over the indices, I could use pointers right away, couldn't I?
I just can't figure out how to get a pointer to Point from an std:.vector<Point>::iterator.

Comment: std::vector<uint32_t>  saves 32 bit on 64 bit system (note it's unsigned)

Comment: If you can use a std::list to store your points, then you could use iterators even if inserting or deleting points.

Comment: @AndyG Iterator and pointer is almost the same thing in the case of the `vector`. Pointer can also become invalid when you modify the collection. If I had to choose between the two, I would choose the iterator, because it is the standard method of position in the vector. The indicator is simply a dirty way to do the same.

Comment: @NO_NAME "indicator" - I meant "pointer". Never use a translator, even if you're in a hurry.

Comment: @NO_NAME: I should have been more clear, the pointers should NOT point at memory addresses within the vector. The `Point` objects themselves can be dynamically allocated, inserted into the first vector (of `Point*`) and then the second vector points at the same memory locations as the first one. The first vector, owning the memory, is responsible for deletion.

Comment: @ChronoTrigger: See my comment to NO_NAME. I'm intending the objects themselves to be dynamically allocated and then given to a vector to hold. The objects definitely will not become invalid if the vector is modified.